# PHP get all images with prefix 1_, 2_, 3_ etc. if they exist in folder

Tags: php, file, exists

**Goal:**
get all images with prefix 1_, 2_, 3_ etc. if they exist in folder

**Question:**
The image names are dynamically added by the db while loop. This returns: 13848. But I need to retrieve: 13848.jpg, 1_13848.jpg, 2_13848.jpg, 3_13848.jpg if they exist.
How to check and return the images that exist with this pattern.

The image name is same as the product_id.
I am getting the name/id part from database query.

**My existing images:**

```
folder_name/13848.jpg
folder_name/1_13848.jpg
folder_name/2_13848.jpg
folder_name/3_13848.jpg
```

**My efforts:**

```
function imageExists($image,$dir) {
$i=1; $try=$image;

while(file_exists($dir.$probeer)) {
    if($image[1] != "_") {
    $try= $i. "_" . $image;
} 
else {
    $try=$image;
    }
$i++;
}

return $try;
}
```

**Using it like so:**

```
while ($r = $q->fetch()) {

$image_folder = "folder_name/";
$image_id = $r['product_id'].".jpg";
$new_imagePath = $image_folder . imageExists($image_id,$image_folder);

echo "<a href='". $imagePath ."'><img class='product' height='' src='". $new_imagePath ."' alt='". $r['product_id']  ."-".  str_replace("'", "", $r['product_name']) . "' title='". str_replace("'", "", $r['product_name']) ."' /></a>";

}
```

Now it returns the images that don't exist:
**folder_name/4_13848.jpg**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The image names are dynamically added by the db while loop. This returns: 13848. But I need to retrieve: 1_13848.jpg, 2_13848.jpg, 3_13848.jpg etc if they exist. Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

```
 $files = glob('FOLDER_PATH/*.{jpg}',GLOB_BRACE);
 function image_exist($files){

  foreach($files as $file){ //retrieves all file name in specified folder
    if (strpos($file, '_') !== false){ //Checks 1_567898.jpg type file exist
       return true;
    }
    else{
       return false;
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for your contribution. Consider adding a textual comment to your answer and not just a snippet.

Comment: @Heena, thanks for your effort, but it just returns true or false. The images are dynamically added. see the Question in my post. I am checking the return of the db cal, not the folder with images .